# Reading and writing to files in python, comparing characters in different files to each other

Tags: python

I want to read 2 files in python, and based off those 2 create another file. The first file contains regular english (ex "hello") and the second file contains "cipher text" (2 5 letter random string Ex "aiwld" and "pqmcx") I want to match up the letter 'h' with the first letter in the cipher text and store it in the third file (the one that we created)

```
def cipher():
    file = english.txt
    file2 = secret.txt
    file3 = cipher.txt

    outputFile = open(file, 'r')
    outputFile = open(file2, 'r')
```

So I have open, for reading, file and file2 and I want to match the first letter in the english.txt with the first letter in the secret.txt and and then write that letter to the cipher.txt file. I am completely lost on where to start and any help would be great.

Do I need to open both files, read from both, somehow compare and then write to the file?
I guess I am really unsure on how to compare individual letters in each file with other individual letters in a different file.

I think I would want something like set english.txt[0] == secret.txt[0] but I am not really sure.

Answer (score 1):

The key thing you're looking at here is how to iterate over a file character by character (rather than the line by line you get more simply).

The simplest solution to this is to read the two files entirely into memory and iterate over them together.  This can be done with the `file.read()` call and the `zip()` built-in.  This suffers because large files would cause us to run out of memory.

Writing out the result is just a normal `file.write()` call.

For example:

```
with open('plaintext.text') as ptf:
    plaintext = ptf.read()
with open('key.txt') as keyf:
    key = keyf.read()

with open('output.txt') as f:
    for plaintext_char, key_char in zip(plaintext, key):
        # Do something to combine the characters
        f.write(new_char)
```

Answer (score 0):

So this might be overly complicated but

```
def cipher(file1 = 'english.txt',
       file2 = 'secret.txt',
       file3 = 'cipher.txt'):
fh1 = open(file1, 'r') # open the files
fh2 = open(file2, 'r')
fh3 = open(file3, 'w+') # write this file if it doesn't exist
ls1 = list() # initiate lists
ls2 = list()
for line in fh1: # add the charecters to the list
    for char in line:
        ls1.append(char)
for line in fh2:
    for char in line:
        ls2.append(char)
if ' ' in ls1: # remove blank spaces
    ls1.remove(' ')
if ' ' in ls2:
    ls2.remove(' ')

    print ls1, ls2

for i in range(len(ls1)): # traverse through the list and write things! :)
    fh3.write(ls1[i] + ' ' + ls2[i] + '\n')
```