# Reading and writing to files in python, translating text in one file to another

Tags: python

I open 2 files and read them. I have a helper function that creates a random 31 character string of the alphabet + ",';.?"

For example the function may create the line "seokgxavu?'bq,cr.ihwt;yjzmdfpnl" which contains all 31 characters and are in a random order, the helper function creates 2 of these lines and writes them to secret.txt.

So say the two random secret lines are:

```
seokgxavu?'bq,cr.ihwt;yjzmdfpnl    
dcurmk'ltbgjyfan?;ohzieps,vxwq.
```

For every letter inside english.txt, each should have its own corresponding secret.txt letter. And every time it does a letter, it will get the next from the other secret line. For example "Hello" would output "vmbja"

v because "h" is where it would be in the first secret line.
m because "e" is where it would be in the second secret line.
b because "l" is where it would be in the FIRST secret line (notice how it went back to the first, this should continue.)

```
with open("english.txt", 'r') as e:
    PlainText = e.read()
with open("secret.txt", 'r') as s:
    SharedKeys = s.read()    


with open("code.txt", 'w') as c:

    x = english[0]               
    y = secret[0]
    x = y



    code.write(str(x))
```

The code above will match up the first letter in the english.txt with the first letter in the secret.txt and then will write that to code.txt. BUT, I am unsure on how to repeat this so that it will do it for an entire paragraph of text. Any tips or pointers are appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: You need to use `for` loops.

Comment: `for c in 'test': print c` will print `t`, `e`, `s`, `t`

Comment: Haven't you asked [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34216141/reading-and-writing-to-files-in-python-comparing-characters-in-different-files) before?

Comment: @cricket_007 are you saying I should break down each of the files into singular letters, then compare from each file at the same index, then write the secret letter to the code.txt?

Comment: Both `SharedKeys` and `PlainText` are simply strings. You can loop over both of those to get single characters. I do not know what your `english` and `secret` variables are. I also fail to see how "Hello" becomes "vmbja" from your example

Comment: @cricket_007 Ok so for "H" it is "v" because if you are to look at where h is in the alphabet (index 8), in secret.txt "v" is at index 8.

Comment: @5gon12eder Yes but that did not include the full alphabet and I did not explain myself well enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got "vmbjc" for "hello" ... I think that is what you meant because when you alternate the secret line, you look for the "o" position in the first secret line, which has a "c". The second secret has as "a" at that position.

```
english = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" + ",';.?"
secret = []
with open("secrets.txt" , "r") as s:
    secret = [line.rstrip() for line in s]

cypher = dict((c, [x[i] for x in secret]) for i, c in enumerate(english))

def translate(s):
    secret_index = 0
    trans = []
    for c in s:
        # not sure how spaces are dealt with
        trans.append(cypher[c][secret_index] if not c == ' ' else ' ')
        secret_index = (secret_index + 1) % len(secret)
    return ''.join(trans)

print(translate("hello")) # vmbjc
```

**UPDATE:** Expanded `cypher` assignment

```
cypher = {}
for i in range(len(english)): # for each english character
    c = english[i]
    secrets = []
    for j in range(len(secret)): # for each corresponding secret character
        secrets.append(secret[j][i])
        cypher[c] = secrets # make a mapping of english character to list-of-secret-characters
    secrets = [] # clear out list of secret characters for the next english character
```

Comment: This is really nice, although I am a beginner in python and do not understand everything going on. (not your fault lol) But, is there a simpler way of doing this? Of course it would take more lines.

Comment: Yeah, I can expand out that `cypher = `  line if you want. I think that is the only "confusing" part here

Comment: That would be great. Also, I am getting english and secret from a file and cannot just have it within the program because secret is randomly generated every time (with a helper function I made) so any hints on how to implement that?

Comment: english you can just keep there, while each secret sequence could be written to separate lines in the sectret file. then you could just do `secret=s.read().split('\n')`, where `s=open('secret.txt','r')`. Assuming no newlines in secret.

Comment: @wahlysadventures - I think `secret = s.readlines()` will return what you want. Assuming each secret is on it's own line as you say. You could also split on `\n` as @M.T says

Comment: @cricket_007  where would secret = s.readlines() fit into the code?

Comment: @wahlysadventures - right after `with open("secret.txt", 'r') as s:`

Comment: It gives me an error saying :string index out of range @cricket_007 This could be due to a personal error on my end since I am looking at your code and implementing it with my own names.

Comment: @wahlysadventures - See my update. But where are you getting that error? In the `translate` method?

Comment: @cricket_007 To be honest, I am super confused now. Do I need the original translate function plus update 1 and update 2?

Comment: @wahlysadventures - Yes, both. Sorry, updated one more time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97685/discussion-between-wahlysadventures-and-cricket-007).

Answer (score 0):

What about using a dictionary to translate from code? You could do something like:

```
e='abcdefghi' #etc.
s='seokgxavu'
s_to_e={}#depending on which you need
e_to_s={}
for i in range(len(e)):#assuming s and e have same length 
    s_to_e[s[i]]=e[i]
    e_to_s[e[i]]=s[i]
code_str='seo'
decoded=''
plain_str='hifi'
encoded=''
for i in range(len(code_str)):
    decoded+=s_to_e[code_str[i]]
for i in range(len(plain_str)):
    encoded+=e_to_s[plain_str[i]]
#encoded should now be 'vuxu' and decoded 'abc'
```

You would have to map whitespace(newline, space, etc.) as well to do a paragraph or more, doing something like:

`s_to_e[' ']=' '`.
or adding it straight to both english and secret as `s='cdfa '`, `e='abcd '`

Comment: I adjusted the answer to be standalone